# error while try to get connection strings for Azure Iot hub in Azure CLI

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-cli2

I want to get connecting string details, as per microsoft document i have run the below command in Azure CLI 2.0. unfortunately it throws below error. i have surfed much in google but i couldn't get apple answer. please can some one help me on this. thanks in advance.

My command :

```
az iot hub device-identity show-connection-string --device-id testDevice
```

Error:

```
az iot hub: 'device-identity' is not in the 'az iot hub' command group. See 'az iot hub --help'.
```

Answer (score 4):

To use this command `az iot hub device-identity show-connection-string --device-id testDevice` you need install [Microsoft Azure IoT Extension](https://github.com/azure/azure-iot-cli-extension) for Azure CLI.

You can install it using the following command:

`az extension add --name azure-cli-iot-ext`

More commands depend on Azure IoT extension are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/azure-cli-iot-ext/iot?view=azure-cli-latest).

Answer (score 0):

For your issue, the answer just as the error saying there is no device-identity in `az iot hub`. If you want to get connection string, you can use [`az iot hub show-connection-string`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/iot/hub?view=azure-cli-latest#az-iot-hub-show-connection-string) or [`az iot device show-connection-string`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/iot/device?view=azure-cli-latest#az-iot-device-show-connection-string)